# Alternative to window.onload event for dynamically building drop downs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a dynamic drop down list. Currently I am building the drop downs on "window.onload" event. But the problem is, I can no longer use windows.onload because this event is now being already used by "myFile.jsp" file which I have included in the body. Since 2 onload events don't work simultaneously, so I am looking for some other way out to build the drop downs. Can you please help. I am very new to web development.

My HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:include page="/myFile.jsp"></jsp:include>
    <table align="center" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
        <tr>
            <td>County Name: </td>
            <td><select id="county"><option value="">Select county</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>City: </td>
            <td><select id="city"><option value="">Select city</option></select></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button  class="btn" onclick="doThis()"">Go</button>
</body>
```

My js file:

```
    function doc(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
        function buildCounty(){
            var opts=doc('county').options;
            for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                opts[opts.length]=new Option(arr[i][0],arr[i][0]);
            }
            doc('county').onchange=function(){
                this.blur();
                var val=this.value;
                if(!val){return;}
                var co=doc('city').options;
                co.length=1;
                for(var j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
                    if(arr[j][0]!==val){continue;}
                    else{
                        var temp=arr[j][1];
                        for(var k=0;k<temp.length;k++){
                            co[co.length]=new Option(temp[k],temp[k]);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        function doThis(){

        }
        window.onload=buildCounty;
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following jQuery...

```
$(function() {
  buildCounty();
});
```

`$(function() {...});` is the equivalent of `window.onload` and will not overwrite any existing calls (e.g. you can have as many of them in your code as you like)

Comment: Where will I be putting this jQuery function. Thanks.

Comment: what's wrong with `$(buildCounty);`? why the extra anon wrapper?

Comment: @dandavis - because I've never actually seen that format before!  If it works, please put as an answer

Comment: @kutta - replace the `window.onload=buildCounty;` with it (or try the code suggested by dandavis!)

Comment: i'm not taking your answer, just reminding that expressions are invisible to js, only values are acted upon...

Comment: @dandavis - apologies, I was not trying to be rude, I honestly have never seen the format before and didn't know it existed.  It's a great bit of knowledge to have

Comment: @kutta - you're welcome. Good luck with the rest of your project. (Feel free to mark as the answer should you wish)